# Analytics solution for Windows 8 javascript application?

Tags: windows-8

What is the preffered method for analytics (e.g. tracking application usage) for a Windows 8 Javascript application? Can I integrate Google Analytics somehow? Or could I use another approach (e.g. Pikwik, Clicky etc)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the most appropriate solution for this: Google Analytics server-side tracking (no need to update client application serving XML content)

http://gadotnet.codeplex.com/